# JScrollpane wont work after ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-jscrollpane

So after I load some content on my div I wanted to initialize jscrollpane, but it just won't work. Here's my code. See if you guys can tell me what is wrong.

Ajax (jquery)

```
   $("#mision").click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        $.ajax({
          url: template + "/acciones.php",
          type: "POST",
          data:  "id=" + id,

          complete: function() {

          },

          success: function(x) {
            $("#cargaContenido").html(x);
                $("#scrollpro").css({'height':(($(window).height())-361)+'px'});
        $('#scrollpro').jScrollPane({

        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
          $('#scrollpro').css({'height':(($(window).height())-301)+'px'});
          $('#scrollpro').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true});
         });
              $("#scrollpro").trigger('resize');

         },

          error: function() {
            //called when there is an error
          },
        });

    });
```

It does work now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#mision").click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax({
      url: template + "/acciones.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  "id=" + id,

      complete: function() {
        $('#cargaContenido').jScrollPane().fadeIn();
      },

      success: function(x) {
        $("#cargaContenido").html(x);

     },

      error: function() {
        //called when there is an error
      },
    });

});
```

Comment: try to do the fadein after the jScrollpane is created

Comment: Try it with out the fadein, also look this [example](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/ajax_example.html)

Comment: i edited my question still no luck at all not even with the api stuff :/

Comment: note that in the example I showed you, they use load(), so to adapt it to your situation you should do this: `$('#cargaContenido').load(template+'/acciones.php?id='+id, '', reinitialiseScrollPane);` , load uses GET requests, so maybe only works with GET requests.

Comment: it does work now butttttt the content doesnt resize and the scrollbar is way to little

Comment: it works now! :) i just decided to insert another div when the the ajax was completed tnx a bunch!

Comment: Cool, please edit your question with the answer, so future readers can  find the answer quickly.

Comment: edited ! remember to have a parent div so u can change the css settings etc (width,overflow:auto) hella late btw srry!

Comment: also added a resize function in case the window height change!

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the fadeIn animation. I don't think jScrollPane can measure the content while its animated. At least it's my guess.

Try this instead:

```
$("#cargaContenido").html(x).fadeIn(500, function() {
    //Callback when the fadeIn is complete
    $('#cargaContenido').jScrollPane();
});
```

Comment: i edited my question still no luck at all not even with the api stuff :/